# Looping javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a script that creates a progress bar and is style with CSS.  It works great, but once the bar reaches the end, it stops and I can not get the script to loop so that it starts again.  How can I loop this script so that the progress bar starts over once it reaches the end?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var el = $(''#progress'');
el.animate({
width: "100%"
}, 40000);
});
</script>


<style>
#progressKeeper {background:#f2f2f2;display:none;width: 400px;height: 18px;border: 1px         solid #CCC;-moz-border-radius:7px; border-radius:7px;color:#f2f2f2;font-family:Arial;font-    weight:bold;font-style:italic;font-size:.9em;margin-bottom:2000px;}
#progress {background: #005c9e;width: 0;height: 17px;-moz-border-radius:7px; border-    radius:7px;}
</style>
```

Comment: One thing that I would try is to wrap the script in a function, and then loop with a certain condition like:

`for (var i=0; i < progressCount; i++) {
  showProgressBar();
}`

You may want to wrap the whole thing in other function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the jQuery, use CSS3!

```css
#progress {
    animation:progress 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:progress 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes progress {from {width:0} to {width:100%}}
@-webkit-keyframes progress {from {width:0} to {width:100%}}
```

If you must support outdated browsers... well, pass a callback to the `animate` function to tell it to start the animation again. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var prog = $("#progress");
    anim();
    function anim() {
        prog.css({width:0});
        prog.animate({width:"100%"},40000,anim);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it a function and pass that function to your `.animate` call as completion handler. See [jQuery().animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animateProgressBar( ) {
        $('#progress').width(0).animate({
            width : "100%"
        }, 40000, animateProgressBar);
    }

    animateProgressBar();
});
```

(Untested)